# Show that that on a line or a column there exists more than 2 perfect square

Tags: combinatorics

A square $10 X10$ is completed with numbers from 1 to 100 such that 2 consecutive numbers are in neighbor little squares.

Show that that on a line or a column there exists more than 2 perfect square.(A perfect square is a positive integer of the form $k^2$)

Looks that there are not too much ways to complete a such square.

Comment: The key fact to note is that the difference between consecutive squares are the odd numbers. This will get you your desired result.

Comment: @DonThousand It’s easy to prove this?

Comment: @alexb That's obvious: color the squares like a chessboard, in black and white. If you put an odd number on a white squre, the next number must be even and it must be on a black square. So all white squares will have odd numbers and all black squares will have even numbers. So the difference between any black square and any white square must be odd, including neighboring ones.